# How to refer to main site tags in Meta SO comments or posts?

Tags: support, tags, markdown

As asked in the title.

Using the `[tag:xxx]` syntax, renders a tag, but won't refer to that tag in the main site, but at Meta Stack Overflow.

Is there a shortcut syntax to provide tag links from the main site?

Comment: What? `[tag:java]` still produces [tag:java] - a link to the main site. If you want a meta tag link, you have to actually write `[meta-tag:java]` to get it.

Comment: @Shog What a silly question (decided not to remove it though, I'll bear the downvotes). I've just noticed that it works as you describe it.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, that was a silly question. I didn't really test that before asking, here are some test cases:

- `[tag:java]` => [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
- `[tag:c++]` => [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

As [@Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) pointed out in [their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317422/how-to-refer-to-main-site-tags-in-meta-so-comments-or-posts/317424#comment312002_317422), the default behavior is that `[tag:xxx]` already links to the tag at the main site, as far it exists.

If there are conflicting tag names on Meta Stack Overflow, these need to be made unambiguous with `meta-` prefixed in the tag qualifier: `[meta-tag:xxxx]`.

Comment: You can (and should) always use meta-tag:... for meta tags and tag:.. for main-site tags. The only place where this ever gets weird is [meta.se], where both refer to the same tags (because MetaSE is its own meta).